# how to run a splunk search for every found orderid

Tags: search, foreach, splunk, spl

I want to first select every ORDERID and then perform a search to every ORDERID I found for that day.

So i need a foreach ORDID. I found just the map command, but it wont work the way I did it.

for my search should be smth like that:

```
`index=* sourcetype=dat ORDID!="" |dedup ORDID| foreach ORDID| ...search
```

And i have to perform it for each ORDID seperatly. so I need to be able to choose the ORDID by smth like $ORDID$.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` command loops over *fields*, not values.  If you had fields called 'ORDID1', 'ORDID2', 'ORDID3', etc., then `foreach ORDID*` would let you process them without listing them all.

You probably want `map`, but you say that didn't work.  Care to elaborate on that?

You might also want to consider using a subsearch to get the ORDID values for a main search.  In Splunk, subsearches are performed before other commands.  Something like this:

```
<your current per-ORDID search> [ index=foo sourcetype=dat ORDID!="" |dedup ORDID | format ]
```

BTW, avoid `index=*` as it's quite costly to search everywhere.

Comment: Thanks of your reply, I dont think It will work even if i select first the ORDID's i want, because im not able to say for every orderid: do smth. like a loop trough every ORDID.

Comment: Please explain more about what you want to do with each ORDID value.  There are commands that can be used to manipulate values.  Focus less on how to do a loop and more on the end goal.

Comment: ok my search now is in a dashboard and select in a few subsearches the materials which are in every Modeltype, and than select the percentage of the $ORDID$ which is passed from another search how many of those most common materials does this ordid got.
But i want to do the search for every Order i get to do a Alert out of it.
so i just have to get every Material of the day e.g. and go trough the search with every material.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: sorry.
I just want to select Ordernumbers for a search. so smth like SELECT ORDID FROM SOURCETYPE 1  into array[] | than i want to be able to reference to every single ORDID like array[1].... array[n] to do something like: array[1] +5 etc

Comment: When you search for something in Splunk, each instance of that something is processed separately.  So, essentially, when you search for ORDID you are looping through each value of ORDID and can use the `eval` command (among others) to do something to the ORDID.